# Name a loader error

Tags: actionscript-3, naming, nomenclature

I wrote a loader class that has a `tries` property that indicates how many times to retry loading a url if an error code is returned. For instance with Twitter, the loader would retry loading a method call if a fail whale is returned, since the next call would probably return success.

I specify the many errors that can be dispatched with string constants, so there's `XMLLoaderError.IO`, `XMLLoaderError.SECURITY`, etc. I'm having trouble thinking of a name for the error dispatched if the number of tries exceeds the `tries` property. At first, I thought `XMLLoaderError.TRIES_EXCEEDED`, but I'm certain there's something better out there. I considered `XMLLoaderError.TIMEOUT`, but timeout is more of a single load error. Or I can be clever and use `XMLLoaderError.TRYOUT` (jk) Any ideas?

Comment: ++ XMLLoaderError.TRIES_EXCEEDED. Or maybe XMLLoaderError.TRY_COUNT_EXCEEDED? Either way it's clear what the error is about...

Comment: 'tries' should probably be 'retries': XMLLoaderError.MAX_RETRIES_EXCEEDED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your other errors indicate the type/genre of error that occurred - ie. "SECURITY" or "IO" - and these are within the XMLLoader context, why not just name it TRY? XMLLoaderError.TRY makes sense to me - or actually, XMLLoaderError.RETRIES probably makes even more sense!

Comment: I actually renamed `tries` to `retryCount`, so the error followed your suggestion as `XMLLoaderError.RETRY_COUNT`.